# Method overloading and passing null

Tags: java, null, overloading

I have the following 2 methods overloaded in a class :

```
public class Test{

  public static void main(String []args) throws ParseException{
       Test t = new Test();
      t.testMethod(null);
  }

  public void testMethod(Object o){
    System.out.println("Object");
  }

  public void testMethod(String s){
    System.out.println("String");
  }
}
```

When I invoke the method `testMethod` it print "String".

When I add one more overloaded method :

```
public void testMethod(StringBuilder sb){
    System.out.println("String");
}
```

It throws me compiler error : `The method testMethod is ambigous for type Test`..

All this happens when I invoke the method with `null`

My questions are :

1. Why it prints String and not Object?
2. Why is there compilation error on adding third method?

Comment: Apart from your specific question, I suggest you avoid having one signature with an Object parm and others with some specific data-type. It might be nice to have it as a catch-all, but they're usually lurking traps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it prints String and not Object?

The java compiler picks the method with the *most specific* or *least generic* argument. Since `Object` is the Superclass of all classes (including `String`), `String` class is picked.

> Why is there compilation error on adding third method?

Since `String` and `StringBuilder` are below `Object`, the compiler will find the call *ambiguous* since both `String` and `StringBuilder` can accept `null`, the compiler fails to determine which method to call hence you get error during compilation.

If you try the same thing with `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException` instead of `String` and `StringBuilder`, you will find out that `FileNotFoundException` is picked since it is least generic.

Answer (score 3):

Method resolution works by selecting the most *specific* method that is applicable for the given arguments. In your first case, `String` is more "specific" than `Object` (since it is a subclass of `Object`) and so the `String` method is chosen.

When you add another method that takes a `StringBuilder`, both that and the `String` method are equally "specific" (they are both direct subclasses of `Object`), so there is an ambiguity as to which should be chosen, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

In case1 String inherits from Object, they are in inheritance chain, null matches both, compiler chooses a more specific type - String.

In case 2 String and StringBuilder are not in inheritance chain, compiler cannot choose a more specific type.

Details of overloaded method resolution are described in JLS 15.12.2.